# Domain PowerShell Policy

Tags: powershell, group-policy

I have created a GPO to enable powershell on our domain PC's.  I'm trying to make it more secure and I'm running into an issue with the following settings:

*Browse to Policies > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Remote Management (WinRM) > WinRM Service

*Set the IPv4 and IPv6 filters to * unless you need something specific there (check out the help on the right).

When I use * in the IPv4 section, my policy works as expected.  When I put in a specific IP address(i.e. my workstation IP address) in cannot connect to a New-PSSession on the target PC.

I have verified the connecting PC when using the * is my ip address by using the netstat -n command.

Any thoughts?

Comment: "...The IPv4 filter specifies one or more *ranges* ..."

Comment: The firewall exception is in place for WinRM.  As I indicated, when I use * it works without issue.  When I use a specific IP address, it doesn't work.  
New-PSSession -ComputerName <targetpc>
Simple command...  * works, 10.10.10.10 doesn't work(where 10.10.10.10 is my IP address).
I have found that there is limited information on setting up WinRM/PowerShell securely on your domain...

Comment: I am aware that you can specify one or more IP addresses in the IPv4 section and that's the point.  If you wanted to secure it to a handful of IP addresses and not *, which is any, than it still should work!

Comment: I'm not connecting to localhost, I'm connecting to a remote host by hostname.  I'm assuming the translation is being done through the domain controller/dns.  As I have indicated, the command "New-PSSession -Computername TargetPC" works when I have the * in the IPv4 address area.  When I try to lock it down to an IP range or specific IP, it stops working.  The particular setting allows only for IP addresses.  If this is not possible, then why have it?  I would think that Microsoft is smarter than that...  >:P  And just to note, I'm making this connection as a Domain Admin.

Comment: I just realized what's going on here, it's restricting the addresses that the server is listening on, not the addresses that are allowed to connect to that server.

Answer (score 1):

It's restricting the addresses that the server is listening on, not the addresses that are allowed to connect to that server.

> The service listens on the addresses specified by the IPv4 and IPv6
>   filters. The IPv4 filter specifies one or more ranges of IPv4
>   addresses, and the IPv6 filter specifies one or more ranges of
>   IPv6addresses. **If specified,the service enumerates the available IP
>   addresses on the computer and uses only addresses that fall within one
>   of the filter ranges.**